# C# add to list of object / architecture matter

Tags: c#, list, object

I have 2 classes:

Car Object

- Id
- Brand
- Color
- List< People > Family

People Object

- Name
- Age

I have to write that data down to the database with Car_id for each People object. So I do something like Car.Family.AddPeople(id, "bob", 25), and that works fine, AddPeople(..) being a function that calls further down to the DB some other lower level functions. Then I add my new item to the collection:

```
Car.Family.Add("bob", 25).
```

It's all good!
Thing is I meant to do it straight away and have a more generic method .Add() :

```
Car.Family.Add(new People("bob", 25)
```

but then, given I'm missing the 'id' (since it's one upper level) to add it to my database, it's not properly recorded. As a result my 'Family' doesn't actualy get populated.

I'm happy to update if that's not clear enough, else any idea of how I should proceed? Much appreciated

Comment: Why not just add the new `People` inside `AddPeople()`, before/after the database insert?

Comment: @user2567674 When you have created a new object of Car class and assigned it properties like id, brand, color. Then you populate Family list. You could pass the whole Car object to the function... I don't quite get the question btw.

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Comment: Looks like I have no choice, I got to parse in my Car.Id property to the constructor for a People :
         
public People(string name, int age, int carId){}